# How to appendChild(element) many times. (The same element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, appendchild

My question is:
Is that possible to add the same element without rewriting the same variable.
I am creating a slider, and i need to append a `div` with a class `slide-el` into block `slider`.
Here is a part of code

```
    var body, html, sliderBody, btnLeft, btnRight, i, parts, vHeight, vWidth;
//Variable definitions
var i = 0,
    parts = 3,

    //Main html elements
    body = document.body,
    html = document.element,

    //viewport Height and Width
    vHeight = window.innerHeight,
    vWidth = window.innerWidth,

    sliderBody = _id("slider"),
    btnLeft = _id("btn-left"),
    btnRight = _id("btn-right"),

    urls = ["http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/pier_1080.jpg",
            "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/pier_1080.jpg",
            "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/pier_1080.jpg",
            "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/pier_1080.jpg"];

    slide = _createEl("div");
    slide.className += "slide-el";

function _id(el){
  return document.getElementById(""+ el +"");
}
function _createEl(el){
  return document.createElement(""+ el +"");
}
window.onload = function(){
  slideLayout();
}

function slideLayout(){
  for(var i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
    sliderBody.appendChild(slide);
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't append the same element that many times. It just creates one element instead of 4.

For you to understand better I made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ud7dvn3z/

Comment: to expand on @smerny's comment: the `.cloneNode()` method of a node will return a copy of the node rather than the node itself, allowing you to use the same base node multiple times. To copy the children of the node as well, you'll need to use `slide.cloneNode(true)` in order to perform a deep copy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) will remove the node from wherever it is before appending it to its new location, so you need to make copies of the node instead. You can use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) for that. The `true` makes `cloneNode` perform a deep clone, i.e. with all its child nodes.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
  sliderBody.appendChild(slide.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: `.cloneNode(true)` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Okey guys! I found an answer. I have to put

```
slide = _createEl("div");
slide.className += "slide-el";
```

into `for` loop.
Now it looks like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
  slide = _createEl("div");
  slide.className += "slide-el";
  sliderBody.appendChild(slide);
}
```