# Only one <br> element is appended in the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, createelement

I am trying to insert three line breaks in the division element, but only one is getting there.

```
    function insertNewGame(linkOfGame, imageOfGame) {
      var para = document.createElement("div");
      var image = new Image(300, 450);
      var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
      var lnBreak = document.createElement("br");
      
      image.src = imageOfGame;
      hyperlink.innerHTML = "Play Now";
      hyperlink.href = linkOfGame;
      
      para.appendChild(image);
      para.appendChild(lnBreak);
      para.appendChild(lnBreak);
      para.appendChild(lnBreak);
      para.appendChild(hyperlink);
      para.style.margin = "20px";
      document.getElementById("gamesList").appendChild(para);

    }
```

What is the problem here? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Variable Referencing the Exact Same Node

`appendChild()` parameter `lnBreak` is the same node so it just takes that exact node that was created and re-appends 2 more times (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635432/2813224)). So you'll need to clone the node, or don't reference the node with a variable, or render an `htmlString`, etc.

In Demo #1 the node `lnBreak` is appended then it's cloned and appended two more times.

```
para.appendChild(lnBreak);
para.appendChild(lnBreak.cloneNode(true));
para.appendChild(lnBreak.cloneNode(true));
```

### Demo #1

```js
function insertNewGame(linkOfGame, imageOfGame) {
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  var lnBreak = document.createElement('br');
  var image = new Image(300, 450);
  var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
  image.src = imageOfGame;
  hyperlink.innerHTML = "Play Now";
  hyperlink.href = linkOfGame;
  para.appendChild(image);

  para.appendChild(lnBreak);
  para.appendChild(lnBreak.cloneNode(true));
  para.appendChild(lnBreak.cloneNode(true));

  para.appendChild(hyperlink);
  para.style.margin = "20px";
  document.getElementById("gamesList").appendChild(para);
}

insertNewGame('about:blank', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/150');
```

```html
<section id='gamesList'></section>
```

---

In Demo #2 a `for` loop is added and the `.createElement()` method is invoked without a variable.

```
for (let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  para.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

### Demo #2

```js
function insertNewGame(linkOfGame, imageOfGame) {
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  var image = new Image(300, 450);
  var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
  image.src = imageOfGame;
  hyperlink.innerHTML = "Play Now";
  hyperlink.href = linkOfGame;
  para.appendChild(image);

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    para.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }

  para.appendChild(hyperlink);
  para.style.margin = "20px";

document.getElementById("gamesList").appendChild(para);
}

insertNewGame('about:blank', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/150');
```

```html
<section id='gamesList'></section>
```

---

In Demo #3 a `htmlString` is rendered into real HTML

```
para.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<br><br><br>`);
```

### Demo #3

```js
function insertNewGame(linkOfGame, imageOfGame) {
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  var image = new Image(300, 450);
  var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
  image.src = imageOfGame;
  hyperlink.innerHTML = "Play Now";
  hyperlink.href = linkOfGame;
  para.appendChild(image);

  para.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<br><br><br>`);

  para.appendChild(hyperlink);
  para.style.margin = "20px";
  document.getElementById("gamesList").appendChild(para);

}

insertNewGame('about:blank', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/150');
```

```html
<section id='gamesList'></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the `<br />` tags in the `appendChild` function.

```js
function insertNewGame(linkOfGame, imageOfGame) {
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  var image = new Image(300, 450);
  var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");

  image.src = imageOfGame;
  hyperlink.innerHTML = "Play Now";
  hyperlink.href = linkOfGame;

  para.appendChild(image);
  para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  para.appendChild(hyperlink);
  para.style.margin = "20px";
  document.getElementById("gamesList").appendChild(para);

}

insertNewGame("", "");
```

```html
<div id="gamesList"></div>
```